# iPhone SDK -> RightBarButtonItem disappears when loading view through AppDelegate

Tags: uinavigationitem, ios5

So I have an issue with my rightbarbuttonitem disappearing. I have two ways of loading this view, first time launch it loads it after user enters in their name (from an initial view). Second time (after the app exits), it checks if the name exists in my stored database and if it does it loads the view right away. This second time is where the button does not show.

The button was set in viewDidLoad of my view originally here (and is still set here for the first load):

```
if (self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem == nil){
    addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(buttonPressed)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
    [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem retain];
}
```

Then in the .m of my AppDelegate, I added the button to think that would resolve it on the second load:

```
if(success){
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    UIViewController *control = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"myNib" bundle:nil];
    [control retain];
    UINavigationController *navControl = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:control];

    [navControl retain];
    [self.window setRootViewController:navControl];

    if (navControl.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem == nil){
        addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(buttonPressed)];
        navControl.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
        [navControl.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem retain];
    }
    //[navControl release];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return;
```

Here's the declaration of the addButton in the header for App Delegate and my view's header:

```
UIBarButtonItem *addButton;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIBarButtonItem *addButton
```

Other posts say to check viewDidLoad/viewWillAppear but putting that first blurb of code in either of those does not solve the issue.

Comment: Upon further thought, I shouldn't have to set adding the button in the AppDelegate.m file correct? As I do call it in my view controller's main and that works (seen in my first launch after the user enters his/her name)

Comment: Can't answer my own question so:

Solved it myself, since the button was never added to the nib, initializing UIViewController doesn't help. I had to initialize my view controller. In other words replace:

    UIViewController *control = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"myNib" bundle:nil];

with:

    MyViewControllerClassName *control = [[MyViewControllerClassName alloc] initWithNibName:@"myNib" bundle:nil];


Hope this helps others in the future, thanks for taking the time to read this if you did!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself, since the button was never added to the nib, initializing UIViewController doesn't help. I had to initialize my view controller.

In other words replace: `UIViewController *control = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"myNib" bundle:nil];` with: `MyViewControllerClassName *control = [[MyViewControllerClassName alloc] initWithNibName:@"myNib" bundle:nil];` Hope this helps others in the future, thanks for taking the time to read this if you did!